# Why is my state removing all of my input when I click on the delete button?

Tags: reactjs

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Input from "./components/Input";

function App() {
  const [newRow, setNewRow] = useState([]);


  const addRow = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNewRow(
      newRow.concat(
        <Input
          key={newRow.length}
          myKey={newRow.length}
          deleteRow={deleteRow}
        />
      )
    );
  };
  const deleteRow = (key) => {
    let filteredRows = newRow.filter((input) => input.key != key);
    setNewRow([...filteredRows]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="calculator">
        <h3>React calculator</h3>
        <button onClick={addRow}>Add row</button>
        <ul>{newRow}</ul>
        <div id="sumID" className="sum-styles"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In my App.js I used concat to add the Input component while also passing the deleteRow as prop to get the key of each Input component from Input.js

And you can see my Input.js here:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const Input = (props) => {

  return (
    <li className="item">
      <select
        className="select__operator"
      >
        <option value="+">+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
      </select>
      <div>
        <span className="num"></span>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="number"
          placeholder="Enter your number here..."
          className="input__number"
        />
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => props.deleteRow(props.myKey)}>Delete</button>
      <button>Disable</button>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

The issue here is that when I have three Input components and click the second row Delete button, my app seems to delete the second **and** the third Input component.

I might have an idea that it could possibly be the way I'm adding components by concat or my filter function is not quite right.

Help would be much appreciated as well as insight (I'm a beginner in Reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

React state should contain only simple objects with strings, arrays & numbers.
They should not contain React elements or DOM elements.

Eg: `this.state = {numbers: [6,4,8,1]}`

When updating state using its previous value, the callback argument should be used.
Otherwise, we may end up using stale state values.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Eg:
`setFruits(fruits=>fruits.concat("apple"))`

Answer (score 0):

Reddit came through and recommended to avoid storing components in a state variable and avoid using index or array lengths as your key

So here is the solution

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Input from "./components/Input";

function App() {
  const [newRow, setNewRow] = useState([]);
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);
  var numbersAll = document.querySelectorAll(".num");

  const OnSaveNumberHandler = (enteredNumbersOp) => {
    const numbersOp = {
      ...enteredNumbersOp,
    };
    // useEffect(() => {
    //   setNumbers(numbersOp);
    // });
  };
  const addRow = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNewRow((prev)=>[...prev, Math.random()])
  };
  const deleteRow = (key) => {
    console.log('logger', { key, newRow });
    let filteredRows = [...newRow];
    filteredRows = filteredRows.filter((input) => input !== key);
    setNewRow(filteredRows);
  };

  if (numbersAll.length > 0) {
    var arr = Object.values(numbersAll).map((el) => el.textContent);
    document.getElementById("sumID").innerHTML = arr
      .map((elt) => parseInt(elt))
      .reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
      });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="calculator">
        <h3>React calculator</h3>
        <button onClick={addRow}>Add row</button>
        <ul>{newRow.map((item) => (
            <Input key={item} myKey={item} deleteRow={deleteRow} onSaveNumber={OnSaveNumberHandler} />
          ))}</ul>
        <div id="sumID" className="sum-styles"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```